# Is there a Chromecast develop/debug APP_ID

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I live in Italy and I cannot buy atm a chromecast to develop with.

I managed to emulate chromecast in my chrome browser thanks to [leapcast](https://github.com/dz0ny/leapcast) but I still cannot develop with it because afik I need a whitelisted APP_ID.

Is there a already whitelisted APP_ID used only for debug/develop mode that I can use in this "special" case?

Comment: Thank you for the reference to leapcast though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Goggle is trying to keep the beta SDK under a certain level of control and in addition the APP_ID whitelists a url (domain?) so even if there was you would need to be able to upload to that URL.

Whitelisting an app is pretty simple and it took me less then a few hours (about 2) to get my App ID. The only necessity is a server (endpoint). You could find some really cheap VPS for about $6 a month. Not sure if they would allow IPs so you will probably need a domain too, about $10 a year.